# Set value (int) to checke radio button wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hope you can help me whit this :)

I WANT TO: give the following values to four different radio buttons: 30, 50, 100 and 200 (doesn't really matter what the values is for now). Right now I need to go into the code and change the number my self. I want these radio buttons to do the job when checked.

I will paste the code here. Can you please be very spesific when explaining this to me (if you can and bother to do so).

Thank you!

```
        //Method for establishing connection to database.      
        // Sette parameter for limit
        public static MongoDatabase GetDatabase(string searchText)

        {
           /* try
            {*/
                TweetOC.Clear();

                MongoServerSettings settings = new MongoServerSettings();
                settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("xxxx", xxxx);
                MongoServer server = new MongoServer(settings);
                MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("tweet_database");
                var collection = database.GetCollection<Tweets>("docs");
                System.Console.WriteLine("5");
                var query = Query.And(Query.Matches("text", searchText),
           Query.NE("geo_enabled", false));

                System.Console.WriteLine("6");
                //var match = Query.ElemMatch("text", query);
                var cursor = collection.Find(query);
            cursor.SetLimit(30);
            System.Console.WriteLine("7");


                //Puts the result from the last query into a list.
                var resultList = cursor.ToList();

                //Iterates over the previous mentioned list and inserts the content into the ObservableCollcetion created earlier.
                foreach (var item in resultList)
                    TweetOC.Add(item);
                System.Console.WriteLine(TweetOC.Count);






                return database;
            }
```

I HAVE TO CHANGE CURSOR.LIMIT(manually) ALL THE TIME. I WANT THIS NUMBER TO CHANGE AUTOMATICALLY WHEN A RADIO BUTTON IS CHECKED.

THE METHOD AND XAML WILL FOLLOW:

```
// I want this to be if radiobutton is 20, then this should be sent to cursor.set limit. I cannot make another string in database.cs without getting an error.
    /*  Private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             var radioButton = sender as RadioButton;
             if (radioButton == 20)
                 return;
             int intIndex = Convert.ToInt32(radioButton.Content.ToString(Cursor.SetLimit));

         }
     * Remember Checked="RadioButton_Checked" in the XAML if you want to try
         */
```

XAML for one of the four buttons:

```
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Margin="20,116,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

HOW SHOULD THIS ACTUALLY LOOK TO GET IT WORKING? PLEASE EDIT THE CODE (if you bother) SO I CAN SEE AND UNDERSTAND THIS.

THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: ALL CAPS makes it look like you're yelling at people

Comment: Haha, I'm sorry. Just wanted to get the thext to really "show up". Hope no offence is taken.

Comment: CAPS is not just associated with yelling it is hard to read.  If you were a gamer you you would know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in an MVVM friendly way, bind the IsChecked property like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=CursorLimit, Converter={StaticResource ParamToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=10}"
```

Set the parameter to the correct value for the given radio button, of course. If you are not familiar with converters, you need a line in your resources like (assuming you have the local xmlns set up to point to the converter namespace):

```
<local:ParamToIntConverter x:Key="ParamToIntConverter"/>
```

Then your converter looks like:

```
public class ParamToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert (...)
   {
       return value.Equals(int.Parse((string)parameter));
   }

   public object ConvertBack(...)
   {
       if ((bool)value)
          return int.Parse((string)parameter);
       else
          return Binding.DoNothing;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xmal code:

```
<RadioButton Content="RadioButton" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Margin="20,116,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" />
```

Your *.cs code:

```
private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... do what you need for this button
}
```

Use different `Checked="[insert_method_name]"` template with equal method names in your *.cs file and do what you need in each method.

Also you can try to make it as in this http://www.dotnetperls.com/radiobutton-wpf example.